# wordpress plugin | short code issue

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

i have develop a wordpress plugin, its very basic and simple. there has a function what is on short code. the problem is when i use that short code on content, plugin content comes on top :(

when i use this short code on page template like "3" no image, it works fine!

4 | http://prnt.sc/c5ohd5
i think problem on loop :( "4" no image shows that loop BTW if you need the total code then plugin link is https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-testimonials-oiiio/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You'll need to show your code for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: And be more specific as to what exactly the issue is, on top you mean like _litterally_ on top (css issue?) on _before_ content.  Also what is your expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code it is impossible to be sure, but my guess is that you're echoing the output of your shortcode instead of returning it.

```
function my_shortcode($atts){
    //do shortcode logic
    echo $result; //This is wrong and would do what you describe.
}

function my_shortcode($atts){
    //do shortcode logic
    return $result; //This is what you should do instead.
}
```

If you have to echo within the plugin you can do this.

```
function my_shortcode($atts){
    ob_start();
    //do shortcode logic
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

That function will store all your `echo` to the output buffer and then return that buffer as a string.